# Could not open "http://.../vv.doc" MessageBox when opening documents in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007, microsoft-office, internet-explorer

When we try to open a document from SharePoint we get a message box with the message "Could not open [docpath]". If we copy the path into word we can access the document. After some seaching on the net we found that if you reset the advanced setting in IE 6 then it sould work, but we did not find what setting that made it not work.

So what setting in IE 6 makes it so that we can't open word document directly in SharePoint 2007?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there something that is blocking your access to the document? For example urlscan?

Answer (score 0):

can you confirm that you've configured the MIME types in IIS as application/msword for .doc & .docx extensions?